# Wowza + nDVR: Sync segments

Tags: nginx, audio-streaming, wowza, http-streaming

I am trying to setup a caching-layer in front of my wowza-servers and seeing a problem i cannot solve.

Situation:
2x Wowza Streaming Engine with nDVR-AddOn activated
12x NginX reverse proxy servers for caching

If both backend-servers (Wowza) are starting to restream and segment my livestreams at the same time, caching works. If they are started apart each other (due to reboot or something), segment-names are not aligned anymore. If the client feches a playlist from A and tries to fetch the Segment from B, it's not there.

Has anybody found a solution for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds as though you should set the chunk ID's to be based on the timecode therefore avoiding the synchronization issue upon the reset scenario.  To do so add the following property:

In the Application.xml under Root/Application/LiveStreamPacketizers/Properties:

```
<Property> 
<Name>calculateChunkIDBasedOnTimecode</Name> 
<Value>true</Value> 
<Type>Boolean</Type> 
</Property>
```

Cheers!